# Cool a room with a fan, what sens orientation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, cooling, fan

It is really hot these days, and at night, I try to cool my room before going to sleep but I'm wondering  in which sens I should orient my Fan

Answer A : Push the hotter air with my fan outside.
[image]

Answer B : Make enter the cooler air into my room
[image]

Answer C : Fan orientation doesn't change anything

Comment: If you have a two story house, the best option is to open some downstairs and upstairs windows, and let natural convection take over as the hot air in your house escapes from the upper windows while pulling cooler outside air in through the lower windows. For our house, that's usually enough. If your bedroom is on the 2nd floor and you still want to use a fan, putting the fan in the window so that it is pushing air out of the window would reinforce the natural air convection direction and perhaps cool your bedroom even faster.